# Gorilla Mux and GORM fail

Tags: go, go-gorm, mux

I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/aspittel/how-i-built-an-api-with-mux-go-postgresql-and-gorm-5ah8) on how to setup a basic API with PostgreSQL, Gorilla Mux and GORM.

This is my app:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

var db *gorm.DB


type Ticket struct {
    gorm.Model
    InfoHash string
    Status   *int `gorm:"default:'0'"`
}


func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost user=user dbname=db_development password=password sslmode=disable")
    db.LogMode(true)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    db.AutoMigrate(&Ticket{})

    router.HandleFunc("/", TicketsIndex).Methods("GET")

    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router)
}

func TicketsIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tickets := []Ticket{}
    db.Find(&tickets)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&tickets)
}
```

The problem is when I visit `localhost:3000`, the server just stops with no error logs, just stops and exit the app. It should return the tickets stored in the database as JSON.

I got it working if I open the database in my TicketsIndex function and close it, like this:

```
func TicketsIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost user=user dbname=db_development password=password sslmode=disable")
  tickets := []Ticket{}
  db.Find(&tickets)
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&tickets)
  defer db.Close()
}
```

But I think this is not the proper way. I also try to move this code into the main function and also works:

```
tickets := []Ticket{}
db.Find(&tickets)
```

So I am assuming it could be the global variable `var db *gormDB` that is not being assigned correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you're typing `db, err := ` you're shadowing the global `var db` with a function-local variable named db, not assigning to the global one. You need to use the equal sign to assign to an already defined var. Also means that you'll need to write `var err error` inside `main` scope.

Comment: That was the answer my friend, I've been struggling with this since yesterday. Write your answer for me to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type `db, err := ...` you're actually shadowing the global `var db` with a function-local variable named db, not assigning to the global one. You need to use the equal sign (`=` vs `:=`) to assign to an already defined var. That also means you'll need to write `var err error` inside of main scope before the assignment, since you're no longer getting declaration automatically from `:=`.